# How to Sum the Values from current date to previous year in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Can any body help me to solve this:

```
 Value  Date

 1000   01-jan-12
 ............
 1000   01-apr-13
```

My Aim is to calculate the sum of marks which secured from current month and year APRIL-13 to Previous one year from Current Month and Year.

Answer (score 0):

your example data shows more that one year from apr 2013.

assuming you wanted to go back to apr-2012

```
select sum(value)
  from your_tab
 where date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm', -12) -- from 1st apr 2012
   and date < trunc(sydate, 'mm');-- anytime up to the end of mar 2013
```

if you wanted to go back to jan of the prior year, then

```
select sum(value)
  from your_tab
 where date >= trunc(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm', -12), 'yy') -- from 1st jan 2012
   and date < add_months(trunc(sydate, 'mm'), 1); -- anytime up to the end of apr 2013
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, But my input in April 2013, but query should calculate from April-2012 to March-2013, It should not include April 2013, Can you give me the solution for this